# Does the number of users ( not logged out ) on app equal no of simultaneous connections on firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app developed and I am expecting more than a 100 users.The app does have a logout button but I doubt any user would logout,they would instead push it to background.
So my question is if I have 150 users ( logged in ,but in background) mean that I have 150 simultaneous connections ? I did read a few questions on simultaneous connections , but can someone be more accurate on what is a concurrent connection.
150 users  - logged in (background) - open app at different times - ?
If this is going to exceed the free plan on firebase , how do i prevent it?.I use email/password for login.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you start an app that uses the Firebase Database, it creates a persistent connection to the Firebase server. This counts as one active connection on the back-end.

The connection can be broken when:

1. the user hasn't written any data and doesn't have any active listeners for a few minutes (currently 5 minutes, but that could change).
2. you call `goOffline()` in your code

Whether the app is in the foreground or background is irrelevant to the Firebase SDK. But you could use Android life-cycle events (such as `onPause()`) to detect such transitions and remove your listeners (to get to condition 1).

Also: when your app is backgrounded, the Android operating system might close the connection from the client to the Firebase back-end at any time. When it does this depends on the version and flavor of Android your device has.

A final option (as fellow Firebaser Doug pointed out in the comments) is to enable automatic resource management. If you enable automatic resource management, the client will essentially call `goOffline()` when the app goes into the background and `goOnline()` when it comes back to the foreground.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to type that out.Pretty clear

Comment: Does setAutomaticResourceManagementEnabled have any bearing on this behavior?
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#setAutomaticResourceManagementEnabled(boolean)

Comment: Uhm... that's a setting I didn't know about. I quickly looked it up and: If you enable that auto resource management, we essentially do `goOffline()` when the app is backgrounded and `goOnline()` when it comes back to the foreground.

Comment: If you have not removed listeners then after 5 minutes, will it automatically break connection with Firebase database ?

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't make sense: how would the server then send updates to the client? As long as there's an active listener, the connection will remain open (unless Android closes it).