# How to close connection with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `Firebase` cloud for my android application. I see there is limit of 100 simultaneous connections in free mode of `Firebase`.

Suppose I have a registration screen in my application and I am trying to create `Firebase` realtime database instance to send user details to the `Firebase` server.

```
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    // get reference to 'users' node
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("users");

    .....
}
```

How I can close my firebase database connection so limit on simultaneous connections will not be crossed.

Doesn't it close connection automatically after certain time ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092157/does-the-number-of-users-not-logged-out-on-app-equal-no-of-simultaneous-conn/43096098#43096098

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may use the activity lifecycle methods like onPause(), onStop() on onDestroy() to close your connection.

Also,Firebase has a goOffline() method , Check the link below

https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_goOffline

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Doesn't it manage automatically ?

Comment: Yes it shuts down firebase connection until goOnline() is called.

Comment: I think we have some language problem. I meant that If I do not close `firebase` database connection by calling `goOffline` method then Doesn't firebase own manage connection and close it own ?